# antd form autoscrolls to bottom while focusing on Input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd library in my project and using Form from antd. Whenever I focus on any input field in that form, it auto scrolls to bottom of that form. I want to disable this scroll while focusing on input fields. The form somewhat looks like below:

```
        <Form
      form={form}
      name="seller_contact_form"
      initialValues={props.initialValues}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      scrollToFirstError
      autoComplete="dontshow"
    >
      <Row justify="center">
        <Col span={20}>
          <div className="gq-order-quantity-wrap">
          <span className="label-paragraph">
            Preferred quantity
          </span>
          </div>
          <Form.Item
            name="quantity"
            style={{ marginBottom: "1em" }}
            rules={[
              {
                required: true,
                message: "Please enter target quantity",
              },
              {
                min: parseInt(inStock <= 0 ? switchMoq : minimumOrderQuantity),
                type: "number",
                message:
                  `Please add quantity equal units`,
              },
              {
                pattern: new RegExp("^[0-9]*$"),
                message: "Please enter in correct format!",
              },
            ]}
          >
            <InputNumber
              onFocus={(e) => gtmFormFunction("quantity", e)}
              onChange={(value) => checkQuantityVal(value)}
              autoComplete="dontshow"
              id={`quantity_${generateRandomString()}`}
              className={'input112'}
            />
          </Form.Item>
```

Please suggest if anyone got any clue on how to fix this. Thanks in advance :)